# Octave: summing indexed elements

Tags: indexing, sum, octave, vectorization, binning

The easiest way to describe this is via example:

```
data = [1, 5, 3, 6, 10];
indices = [1, 2, 2, 2, 4];
result = zeroes(1, 5);
```

I want `result(1)` to be the sum of all the elements in `data` whose index is `1`, `result(2)` to be the sum of all the elements in `data` whose index is `2`, etc.

This works but is really slow when applied (changing `5` to `65535`) to 64K element vectors:

```
result = result + arrayfun(@(x) sum(data(index==x)), 1:5);
```

I think it's creating 64K vectors with 64K elements that's taking up the time. Is there a faster way to do this? Or do I need to figure out a completely different approach?

---

```
for i = [1:5]
    idx = indices(i);
    result(idx) = result(idx) + data(i);
endfor
```

But that's a very non-octave-y way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing how MATLAB is very similar to Octave, I will provide an answer that was tested on MATLAB R2016b. Looking at the [documentation of Octave 4.2.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Accumulation.html#Accumulation) the syntax should be the same.

All you need to do is this:

```matlab
result = accumarray(indices(:), data(:), [5 1]).'
```

Which gives:

```
result =

     1    14     0    10     0
```

Reshaping to a column vector (`arrayName(:)` ) is necessary because of the expected inputs to `accumarray`. Specifying the size as `[5 1]` and then transposing the result was done to avoid some MATLAB error.

`accumarray` is also described in depth in the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

Comment: Exactly the function I wanted and didn't know existed. Thanks!